# Handsontable not recognising custom formula

Tags: vue.js, handsontable

I created a simple handsontable with a custom formula, but I cannot get it to work.

I followed the example in the HyperFormula docs but the function is not being recognised by the library.

Here is an example:

[image: Edit epic-cannon-1fz4m6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated for everyone looking for the answer https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-worker-yjcsjw the `HyperFormula.registerFunctionPlugin` has to be called before the instance is created. It is mentioned here in the docs: https://hyperformula.handsontable.com/api/classes/hyperformula.html#registerfunctionplugin